# SQL search design

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am building a documents archive form my company in SQL database.
I need the design to allow be fast stable and scalable search ability.
there are 2 options that came in mind:

### Option 1:

```
Fields Table
key     Name                Type           allow Null
(pk)    field_id            bigint         FALSE
        field_name          varchar(100)   FALSE
        field_type          tinyint        FALSE
        field_max_length    int            TRUE
(fk)    field_label_keyId   decimal        TRUE
        field_rules         xml            TRUE
        field_defaults      xml            TRUE
        field_hierarchy     hierarchyid    TRUE

Fields for Site Table
key     Name                Type           allow Null
(pk)    field_site_id       bigint         FALSE
(fk)    field_id            bigint         FALSE
(fk)    site_id             varchar(50)    FALSE

Fields Values Table
key     Name                Type            allow Null
(pk)    doc_field_value_id  bigint          FALSE
(fk)    field_id            bigint          FALSE
(fk)    doc_id              varchar(50)     FALSE
        field_value         nvarchar(4000)  TRUE
```

Where I would go:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM [Fields Values Table]
 WHERE doc_id IN
      (SELECT doc_id 
         FROM [Fields Values Table]
        WHERE [field_id] = 1 AND [field_value]=1)
          AND (doc_id IN
              (SELECT doc_id
                 FROM [Fields Values Table]
                WHERE [field_id] = 2 AND [field_value]=2
               ...
              )
       )
.
.
.
```

(For as many search parameters as needed)

- This option is scalable and more storage efficient.
- The problem is searching the data based on different search criteria.

### Option 2:

```
Fields Values Table
key Name    Type    allow Null
(pk)    doc_field_value_id  bigint  FALSE
    S1  nvarchar(50)    TRUE
    S2  nvarchar(50)    TRUE
    S3  nvarchar(50)    TRUE
    S4  nvarchar(50)    TRUE
    S5  nvarchar(50)    TRUE
    S6  nvarchar(50)    TRUE
    .   .   .
    .   .   .
    .   .   .
    S(N)    nvarchar(50)    TRUE
```

where I will go:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Fields Values Table]
WHERE [S1]=1 AND [S2]=2 AND [S3]=3
```

- This option is less scalable and less storage efficient, but is also less IO demanding and might be easier to maintain.

### Question:

Each design has its drawbacks, but I need to know which is best and is there another option that I haven't considered.

Comment: By the way, multi WHERE IN statements are not scalable. Espessialy, in case when they return many records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What types of queries are people going to ask?

- Searching for one term on its own is the obvious and simplest case, and probably also the most common case.
- What about 'term1 AND term2'?
- What about 'term1 OR term2'?
- What about wild-carding?
- What about 'term1 AND NOT term2'?
- What about nesting conditions in parentheses?

In many ways, though, it doesn't matter.  The first solution is the way to go.  Quite apart from the fact that it is more nearly normalized, your outline query for option 2 is inaccurate, and so is misleading you about the (absence of) benefits of the organization.

Suppose someone is searching for 'term1' and 'term2' and 'term3'.  Each of those values can be stored in any of the S<sub>N</sub> columns, so the query is not:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Fields Values Table]
WHERE [S1]=1 AND [S2]=2 AND [S3]=3
```

but

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Fields Values Table]
WHERE ([S1] = 'term1' OR [S2] = 'term1' OR ... OR [SN] = 'term1')
  AND ([S1] = 'term2' OR [S2] = 'term2' OR ... OR [SN] = 'term2')
  AND ([S1] = 'term3' OR [S2] = 'term3' OR ... OR [SN] = 'term3')
```

Your nominal solution could only work if you can pre-identify and encode in your table schema every possible search term - and (believe me) you can't do that.  And, if your system did limit the search terms to only those that it knows about, then people won't use it, because it won't be flexible enough or powerful enough.

So, go with Option 1.

---

The nested query solution in the question is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Fields Values Table]
WHERE doc_id IN
     (SELECT doc_id 
        FROM [Fields Values Table]
       WHERE [field_id] = 1 AND [field_value]=1)
         AND (doc_id IN
             (SELECT doc_id
                FROM [Fields Values Table]
               WHERE [field_id] = 2 AND [field_value]=2
              ...
             )
      )
```

I think this should be written using JOIN notation, which avoids as much nesting of the SQL, without altering the execution plan very much (beyond making it easier for the optimizer to decide which queries to do first):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM [Fields Values Table] AS T1
  JOIN [Fields Values Table] AS T2
    ON T1.Doc_ID = T2.Doc_ID AND T2.Field_ID = 2 AND T2.Field_Value = 2
  JOIN [Fields Values Table] AS T3
    ON T1.Doc_ID = T3.Doc_ID AND T3.Field_ID = 3 AND T3.Field_Value = 3
 WHERE T1.Field_ID = 1 AND T1.Field_Value = 1
```

Or even:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT Doc_ID
          FROM [Fields Values Table]
         WHERE Field_ID = 1 AND Field_Value = 1
       ) AS T1
  JOIN (SELECT Doc_ID
          FROM [Fields Values Table]
         WHERE Field_ID = 2 AND Field_Value = 2
       ) AS T2
    ON T1.Doc_ID = T2.Doc_ID
  JOIN (SELECT Doc_ID
          FROM [Fields Values Table]
         WHERE Field_ID = 3 AND Field_Value = 3
       ) AS T3
    ON T1.Doc_ID = T3.Doc_ID
```

This is even more symmetric.